# Non prime number test

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Suppose $a\geq 3, n\geq 3$ are integers. I claim that if $gcd(a, n)=1$, then $a^n+n^a$ is not a prime. I am trying find a counter example but till now I did not reach there.

Answer (score 1):

$a=24,n=5$ gives $$59\ 604\ 644\ 783\ 353\ 249$$, which is prime.

You asked in a comment how we know these are primes. Software. The exceptions to your conjecture are all fairly big. The next biggest after 5,24 and 3,56 include 54,7 and 69,8 and 76,9 and 15,32 etc. Manual calculation is not feasible.

Of course one might try to construct by hand a reason why there are (probably) infinitely many cases, but you did not ask for that. You just asked whether there were counter-examples.

Comment: 7^4+4^7=5*3757@almagest

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer, the smallest example could be done by hand, but even a strong pseudoprime-test to base $2$ would be difficult.

Comment: The question whether inifinite many primes (and therefore counterexamples) exist is very interesting, but a proof or disproof is probably out of reach. There should be infinite many primes of the required type.

Answer (score 1):

The following PARI/GP-program shows the pairs $3\le a<n\le 100$ with $gcd(a,n)=1$, such that $a^n+n^a$ is prime. The smallest prime occuring is $5^{24}+24^5$.

```
? for(a=3,100,for(n=a+1,100,if((gcd(a,n)==1)*(isprime(a^n+n^a,2)==1),print(a," "
,n))))
3 56
5 24
7 54
8 69
9 76
15 32
21 68
33 38
34 75
56 87
80 81
?
```

So, the claim is false, but the smallest prime has $17$ digits.

Hand calculation would not be completely impossible, but it would take very long and the danger of an error would be great.

A strong pseudoprime-test to base $2$ could be done by hand, but it would still be difficult to actually do that.

Answer (score 0):

Take for example $a=3,n=56$. Then $3^{56}+56^3$ is prime.

Another example $a=5,n=1036.$ Then $5^{1036}+1036^5$ is prime, as well.

Comment: How do u know that these are prime numbers ?

Comment: @ArmanMalekzade http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=PrimeQ%5B3%5E(56)%2B56%5E3%5D